# Halfwidth vs Fullwidth Forms in JIS X 208

Tags: character-encoding, cjk, iconv, shift-jis

I am trying to make sense of the following explanation on [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0208#Character_set_0x21_(row_number_1,_special_characters)):

> ASCII and JISCII punctuation (shown here with a yellow background) may
> use alternative mappings to the Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms block if
> used in an encoding which combines JIS X 0208 with ASCII or with JIS X
> 0201, such as Shift JIS, EUC-JP or ISO 2022-JP.

On my ubuntu system I can verify that:

```
$ printf "\x1b\x24\x42\x24\x22\x21\x40\n" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 24 42 24 22 21 40 0a                           |.$B$"!@.|
00000008
```

Gives:

```
$ printf "\x1b\x24\x42\x24\x22\x21\x40\n" | iconv -f iso-2022-jp -t utf8
あ＼
```

And we can verify the last character is U+FF3C FULLWIDTH REVERSE SOLIDUS using something like:

```
$ printf "\x1b\x24\x42\x24\x22\x21\x40\n" | iconv -f iso-2022-jp -t utf16be | hexdump -C
00000000  30 42 ff 3c 00 0a                                 |0B.<..|
00000006
```

My question is how do I switch to the "Halfwidth form" ? My question is about JIS X 208 and not iso-2022-jp, I'd like to understand what is the correct escape character to switch to halfwidth according to JIS X 208 specification.

---

Updated.

Since U+FF3C FULLWIDTH REVERSE SOLIDUS is an issue for JIS X 201 (¥). How about the case with U+FF0F FULLWIDTH SOLIDUS. Let's consider the following input: `Ａ／ア￥A/ｱ¥`.

I would be tempted to say this is written as:

```
$ printf "\x1b\x24\x42\x23\x41\x21\x3f\x25\x22\x21\x6f\x1b\x28\x4a\x41\x2f\xb1\x5c" | hexdump -C
00000000  1b 24 42 23 41 21 3f 25  22 21 6f 1b 28 4a 41 2f  |.$B#A!?%"!o.(JA/|
00000010  b1 5c                                             |.\|
00000012
```

Could someone confirm that the only way to have Halfwidth form with JIS X 208 is to use an escape sequence to JIS X 201:

- ESC 02/08 04/10 (`ESC(J`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't expect this to be possible. The halfwidth characters generally come out of how Shift JIS (and similar) interprets JIS X 201 characters. They're not actually part of the JIS X 208 character set. There isn't a "halfwidth mode" so much as a "JIS X 201 mode, which are generally taken to be halfwidth."

JIS X 201 doesn't have a `\` (REVERSE SOLIDUS) character. It was replaced by `¥` (YEN SIGN). (To the great frustration of C programmers....) So I wouldn't expect there to be a way to encode a hypothetical "HALFWIDTH REVERSE SOLIDUS" in JIS X 208. And it doesn't exist in Unicode (these are related facts).

It might be possible to encode this in [IBM Code Page 896](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_896) as 0x63, or in some of the other IBM Japanese code pages. But I wouldn't expect it in JIS X 208.

Comment: yes, I believe your update is correct. I don't think there are any "halfwidth characters" in JIS X 208. There are just encodings like Shift JIS that support both 201 and 208, and 201 characters are interpreted as halfwidth.

Comment: Someone would need to edit the wikipedia page at least to clarify that '\' REVERSE SOLIDUS is impossible in JIX X 208 (only FULLWIDTH) ...